# Editing public profile listing view template

Tags: wordpress, profile

We are not wanting to have the links on a profile view page to query the data. For instance, an email link should be 'mailto:' and not search function. I viewed the page as see

```
<!-- .tpl file invoked: CRM/Profile/Page/View.tpl. Call via form.tpl if we have a form in the page. -->
```

as the template but in the code I do not see how to change. Alternatively, removing all link on the view profile page would also work.

Comment: I used pointer-events:none CSS in a View.extra.tpl file but I would like to be more specific to a certain profile. However, adding that profile in the directory did not apply the code ... https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/framework/templates/customizing/#custom-profile-contribution-event-registration-screens.

Comment: what CMS is this?

Comment: WP... trying to make use of profiles. It's all we got.

Comment: can you screenshot your profile settings? isn't there a way to set it to eg List but not Search?

Comment: There is no such setting

Comment: Right, I think I was partly thinking of 'Expose Publicly' or 'Expose Publicly and for Listings' but that isn't what you need either

Answer (score 1):

You can simply set a field's Visibility setting to `Expose Publicly` and it will not use the field as a search function.

From the Visibility field helper text:

> When visibility is 'Expose Publicly and for Listings', users can also
>   click the field value when viewing a contact in order to locate other
>   contacts with the same value(s) (i.e. other contacts who live in
>   Poland).